# modify to remove initial ul tag

Tags: php

How can I adjust this code so that the very first ul tag is removed from the generated list? is it even possible to do that?

this would be the result I would like to get:

```
<ul>  <--remove this initial tag
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

list generator

```
 function buildMenu($parent, $menu)
    {
       $menulist = "";
       if (isset($menu['parents'][$parent]))
       {
          $menulist .= "<ul>\n";
           foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)
           {
              if(!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
              {
                 $menulist .= "   <li><a href='".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menuURL']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menuName']."</a></li> \n";
              }
              if(isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
              {
                 $menulist .= "   <li><a href='".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menuURL']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menuName']."</a>";
                 $menulist .= buildMenu($itemId, $menu);
                 $menulist .= "</li> \n";
             }
             }
             $menulist .= "</ul> \n";
       }
       return $menulist;
    }?>
```

Comment: Removing that `ul` element would create invalid HTML?

Comment: true enough, my plan was to manually add the initial ul tag along with a class tag for some css. I tried adding it directly into the code above but it adds the class tag to every ul tag that is generated by the function..... option 2 would be to find a way to add the class tag to just the initial ul tag.

Answer (score 1):

Set a delimiator. Notice the $first added to the function vars and then FALSE for every other call toward the bottom

```
function buildMenu($parent, $menu, $first = TRUE)
{
   $menulist = "";
   if (isset($menu['parents'][$parent]))
   {
       $menulist .= $first ? "" : "<ul>\n";
       foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)
       {
          if(!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
             $menulist .= "   <li><a href='".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menuURL']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menuName']."</a></li> \n";
          }
          if(isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
             $menulist .= "   <li><a href='".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menuURL']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menuName']."</a>";
             $menulist .= buildMenu($itemId, $menu, FALSE);
             $menulist .= "</li> \n";
         }
         }
         $menulist .= "</ul> \n";
   }
   return $menulist;
}?>
```

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
$menulist .= "<ul>\n";
```

by

```
$menulist .= strlen($menulist) ? "<ul>\n":"";
```

Comment: This will always append `"<ul>\n"` to `$menulist` since that line is NOT within a loop. It's within an `if` statement.